# Apply a Rewrite Rule to Multiple Directories

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

The following .htaccess code redirects my clients dynamic (popcorn) product pages, removes the query string, and replaces the URL encoded '+' with more SEO friendly '-'.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^+\s]+)(?:[+\s]+)([^+\s]+)((?:[+\s]+).*)$ $1-$2$3 [DPI,N]
RewriteRule ^([^+\s]+)(?:[+\s]+)([^+\s]+)$ $1-$2 [R=301,DPI,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^shop/popcorn/(.*)$ shop/popcorn/product.php?subject=$1 [L,B,NC]
```

The resulting URL's appear as such:

**campbellssweets.com/shop/popcorn/Sea-Salt-and-Cracked-Pepper-Popcorn**

My question is if / how I can apply that same code to other folders in the shop directory:

i.e.

**campbellssweets.com/shop/sweets/**

**campbellssweets.com/shop/cupcakes/**

Answer (score 0):

Just make your last rule little more generic:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(shop/[^/]+)/(.*)$ $1/product.php?subject=$2 [L,B,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: that modified RewriteRule did properly format the URL's in all three of the 'Shop' sub directories (popcorn, sweets and cupcakes) however, while the links are formatted correctly, they are resulting in a 404 Server Error - The requested URL /campbells/shop/popcorn/product.php was not found on this server.